# how to fix it : Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int in

Tags: php, pdo

I have error like this:

> Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int & Undefined
>   property: stdClass::$tugas

in function:

```
public function cekNilai($id_mhs){

    $sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) from nilai WHERE id_mhs =:id_mhs';
    $query = $this -> conn -> prepare($sql);
    $query -> execute(array('id_mhs'=>$id_mhs));
    if($query){

        $row_count = $query -> fetchObject();

        if ($row_count == 0){

            return false;

        } else {
            echo $row_count->tugas;
            return true;

        }
    } else {

        return false;
    }

}
```

My Database:

[image]

Comment: where from your value : $id_mhs your sure it's an INT ? Make an var_dump($id_mhs); to seen what is contain

Comment: Try `var_dump($row_count);` to see what it contains. You can also check `if(empty($row_count))` instead of checking it against 0.

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) AS recordCount FROM nilai WHERE id_mhs = :id_mhs` then `$row_count = $query->fetchObject()->recordCount` - or something along those lines.

Comment: `Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int`. You received it since the `$row_count` is an object now and PHP tried to convert it to int in `if ($row_count == 0)` since you are making a `non-strict` comparison.

Answer (score 2):

This call to the [`fetchObject()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchobject.php) method returns an object containing the queried values, or `FALSE` on failure. But here you're comparing it to an integer, which isn't what you want:

```
$row_count = $query -> fetchObject();
if ($row_count == 0){
```

Also note, you're querying for a row count:

```
$sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) from nilai WHERE id_mhs =:id_mhs';
```

This will return a single value (the count) -- *not* a row. But then you're trying to extract a column from the object, this won't work, because there is no `tugas` value in the object:

```
return $row_count->tugas;
```

You probably want something like this:

```
$row_count = $query->fetchColumn();
return $row_count > 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Missing ":" in execute.

```
$query->execute(array(':id_mhs' => $id_mhs));
```

## edit

```
public function cekNilai($id_mhs){

    $sql    = 'SELECT tugas from nilai WHERE id_mhs = :id_mhs';
    $query  = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute(array(':id_mhs' => $id_mhs));
    if($query)
    {
      $row_count = $query->fetchObject();

        if ( ! $row_count )
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            echo $row_count->tugas;
            return true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note these colons are not required.

Comment: this should be a comment

Comment: @ErisanOlasheni - too low reputation to send comments.. :-(

Comment: ok, but the fact the you have a low reputation to add comments does not mean you should abuse the Answer system. Take note.

Comment: @ErisanOlasheni - Thank you for the information. I am new here, but to help :)